# div moving to right instead of left

Tags: html, css

i have multiple div which is getting stacked in rows, each has have two divs.

but div is not aligned properly, and moving to right , instead of left.

```
 <div className="col-md-6 adminForm borderItem" >
      <label htmlFor="description">Date Added</label><span className='errorMsg'>  {fuelStock.addedDttmError}</span>
      <DatePicker selected={addedDTTM} placeholderText="Select a date" timeInputLabel="Time:" name="added_dttm" id="added_dttm" className="form-control" onChange={date => handleDttmOfSale(date)} dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa" showTimeInput />
    </div>

    <div className="col-md-6 adminForm borderItem">
      <label htmlFor="volume">Fuel Price</label><span className='errorMsg'>  {fuelStock.fuelPriceError}</span>
      <NumberInput autoComplete="off" id="fuelPrice" name="fuelPrice" isDecScaleEnabled={true} decimalScale={2}
        value={fuelStock.fuelPrice} className="form-control"
        onChange={(value) => handleInputChange(value, "fuelPrice")}></NumberInput>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-6 adminForm borderItem" style={{position:'relative'}}>
      <label htmlFor="commission">commission</label><span className='errorMsg'>  {fuelStock.commissionError}</span>
      <NumberInput autoComplete="off" id="commission" name="commission" isDecScaleEnabled={true} decimalScale={2}
        value={fuelStock.commission} className="form-control"
        onChange={(value) => handleInputChange(value, "commission")}></NumberInput>
    </div>


.adminForm {
   float: left;
   padding-top: 10px;
 }
```

but i am getting as below

[image]

how to align move div to left, i know the above has occupied some space, but i need to move to left,i tried positions and float:left , but didnt work

Comment: Can you please show the HTML output, not the framework code. This is so that we can create a working example of the issue. Also, this appears to be a CSS issue, not a JS one, so I've retagged the question for you

Comment: You should have a look at flexbox or grid. I think there also might be some important css rules on your side missing to get the full picture.

Comment: how to create html output.?

Answer (score 0):

as i see you are working with bootstrap so you don't need to add any extra styling for left just follow the bootstrap structure you will get what you want like this

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">first div</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">second div</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">third div</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">fourth div</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

use **mb-3** class for margin you don't need to additionally add **adminForm ** style for your code it will work like this hope you added container and row above the code for getting the styling of container and row

**Note : add container and row before using col class**

```
<div className="col-md-6  borderItem" >
  <label htmlFor="description">Date Added</label><span className='errorMsg'>  {fuelStock.addedDttmError}</span>
  <DatePicker selected={addedDTTM} placeholderText="Select a date" timeInputLabel="Time:" name="added_dttm" id="added_dttm" className="form-control" onChange={date => handleDttmOfSale(date)} dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa" showTimeInput />
</div>

<div className="col-md-6  borderItem">
  <label htmlFor="volume">Fuel Price</label><span className='errorMsg'>  {fuelStock.fuelPriceError}</span>
  <NumberInput autoComplete="off" id="fuelPrice" name="fuelPrice" isDecScaleEnabled={true} decimalScale={2}
    value={fuelStock.fuelPrice} className="form-control"
    onChange={(value) => handleInputChange(value, "fuelPrice")}></NumberInput>
</div>
<div className="col-md-6  borderItem">
  <label htmlFor="commission">commission</label><span className='errorMsg'>  {fuelStock.commissionError}</span>
  <NumberInput autoComplete="off" id="commission" name="commission" isDecScaleEnabled={true} decimalScale={2}
    value={fuelStock.commission} className="form-control"
    onChange={(value) => handleInputChange(value, "commission")}></NumberInput>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To align the divs to the left, you can use the following CSS:

```
.adminForm {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  clear: left;
}
```

The `clear: left;` property will prevent the divs from wrapping around other elements that are floated to the left.

Here is a breakdown of the CSS:

- `float: left;`: This property floats the div to the left, allowing it to move to the left of other elements.
- `padding-top: 10px;`: This property adds 10 pixels of padding to the top of the div, creating some space between the div and the element above it.
- `clear: left;`: This property prevents the div from wrapping around other elements that are floated to the left.

You can also use the `margin-left` property to move the div to the left. For example:

```
.adminForm {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

The `margin-left` property will add 10 pixels of space to the left of the div, moving it to the left.

I hope this helps!

Comment: clear left clears all div and moves to left, instead of placing at right side